# How do I make `clrscr()` clear the screen in black color?

Tags: colors, turbo-c++

Whenever I call `clrscr()` in Turbo C++, it clears my screen in a *gray* background color, but I want it to clear the screen in *black*. What should be done to clear the screen in a *black* background?

Comment: i think it's nothing related to clrscr() but editor settings

Answer (score 0):

`clrscr()` in Turbo C++ clears the screen using the current `textbackground()` color.

If you don't care about the `textcolor()` then simply write:

```
#include <CONIO.H>
...
textbackground(BLACK);
clrscr();
```

If you do care about the `textcolor()`, you can either write:

```
#include <CONIO.H>
...
textcolor(WHITE);
textbackground(BLACK);
clrscr();
```

or combine `textcolor()` and `textbackground()` into `textattr()` writing:

```
#include <CONIO.H>
...
textattr((BLACK << 8) + WHITE);
clrscr();
```